# Content database schema version is not supported in the new farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I never did this before, so I want to make sure it is correct.

I have a development SP standalone machine (A), it has SQL2008R2+SP2013. it was setup by others. Now, we decided to setup a a farm (B) with SQL2012+SP2013, separate the SQL and SP, and want to keep all content and customization on the Dev box.

I setup new SP farm, backup content database on A, and restore it on B. then try to attach it to a web app on B. Then it shows this error:

> **Content database schema version is not supported in the new farm**

Then I realized that the Dev SP has many patches installed. Based on build number and CU listed at http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx , Dev SP was SPS2013 RTM, 15.0.4420.1017. Then installed each update, PU, CU until 15.0.4535.1000. The content database setting shows:

> Database Schema Versions
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence Current Schema Version: 15.0.145.0, Maximum Schema Version: 15.0.145.0 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence2 Current Schema Version: 15.0.14.0, Maximum Schema Version: 15.0.14.0 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase Current Schema Version: 15.0.4535.1000, Maximum Schema Version: **15.0.4535.1000**

My question is: Do I have to install each PU & CU listed? Or, I can simply install the ones on March and Augest (4535.1000) (in order to install August one, have to install March one first)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install March pu(which is mandatory) and then installed the August cu. Recent CU contains all previous release till base(in this case March PU).

Comment: thanks. do I have to install PU, then config it using wizard, then install CU, then config again? or, I can just install PU + CU, config once? thanks again.

Comment: what I am  thinking about March PU as it is mandatory for any CU for SharePoint 2013. Config wizard is only way to upgrade the Build version. for this reason i would go March PU > Config wizard > CU > Config wizard.

Comment: bad luck, one of our guy already did PU+CU. I'll do psconfig to see whether it had any problems. luckily, I have farm backup before PU+CU (for worse case). thanks.